# How to accumulate unique sum of columns across pandas index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas DateFrame, df which I created with

```
df = pd.read_table('sorted_df_changes.txt', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, names=['date', 'rev_id', 'score'])
```

which is structured like so:

```
                     page_id     score  
date
2001-05-23 19:50:14  2430        7.632989
2001-05-25 11:53:55  1814033     18.946234
2001-05-27 17:36:37  2115        3.398154
2001-08-04 21:00:51  311         19.386016
2001-08-04 21:07:42  314         14.886722
```

date is the index and is of type DatetimeIndex.

Every page_id may appear in one or more dates (not unique) and is large in size ~1 million. All of the pages together make up the **document**.

I need to get a score for the entire **document** at every time in date while only counting the latest score for any given page_id.

### Example

#### Example Data

```
                     page_id     score  
date
2001-05-23 19:50:14  1           3
2001-05-25 11:53:55  2           4
2001-05-27 17:36:37  1           5
2001-05-28 19:36:37  1           1
```

#### Example Solution

```
                     score  
date
2001-05-23 19:50:14  3
2001-05-25 11:53:55  7 (3 + 4)
2001-05-27 17:36:37  9 (5 + 4)
2001-05-28 19:36:37  5 (1 + 4)
```

The entry for 2 is counted continuously since it is not repeated but each time id 1 is repeated the new score replaces the old score.

Comment: Why `5 + 4 = 5` in the third day?

Comment: That is the total score at that time. page_id 1 should only be counted once (most recent score). so 5 from page_id 1 on 05-27 and 4 from page_id 2 so `5 + 4 = 9`

edit: I must be tired, but yeah the reasoning was correct but it should be 9 sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:

Finally, I found a solution that don't need for loop:

```
df.score.groupby(df.page_id).transform(lambda s:s.diff().combine_first(s)).cumsum()
```

I think a for loop is needed:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
txt = """date,page_id,score
2001-05-23 19:50:14,  1,3
2001-05-25 11:53:55,  2,4
2001-05-27 17:36:37,  1,5
2001-05-28 19:36:37,  1,1
2001-05-28 19:36:38,  3,6
2001-05-28 19:36:39,  3,9
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), index_col=0)

def score_sum_py(page_id, scores):
    from itertools import izip
    score_sum = 0
    last_score = [0]*(np.max(page_id)+1)
    result = np.empty_like(scores)
    for i, (pid, score) in enumerate(izip(page_id, scores)):
        score_sum = score_sum - last_score[pid] + score
        last_score[pid] = score
        result[i] = score_sum
    result.name = "score_sum"
    return result

print score_sum_py(pd.factorize(df.page_id)[0], df.score)
```

output:

```
date
2001-05-23 19:50:14     3
2001-05-25 11:53:55     7
2001-05-27 17:36:37     9
2001-05-28 19:36:37     5
2001-05-28 19:36:38    11
2001-05-28 19:36:39    14
Name: score_sum
```

If the loop in python is slow, you can try to convert the two series page_id, scores to python list first, loop over list and calculation with python's native integer maybe faster.

If speed is important, you can also try cython:

```
%%cython
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

@cython.wraparound(False) 
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def score_sum(np.ndarray[int] page_id, np.ndarray[long long] scores):
    cdef int i
    cdef long long score_sum, pid, score
    cdef np.ndarray[long long] last_score, result

    score_sum = 0
    last_score = np.zeros(np.max(page_id)+1, dtype=np.int64)
    result = np.empty_like(scores)

    for i in range(len(page_id)):
        pid = page_id[i]
        score = scores[i]
        score_sum = score_sum - last_score[pid] + score
        last_score[pid] = score
        result[i] = score_sum

    result.name = "score_sum"
    return result
```

Here I use `pandas.factorize()` to convert the `page_id` to an array in range 0 and N. where N is the unique count of elements in `page_id`. You can also use a dict to cache the last_score of every page_id without using `pandas.factorize()`.

Comment: I am getting an exception on the transform call because I have duplicate index values. `Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` I am extremely new to pandas. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: You can call `df2 = df.reset_index()`, and then use df2 to calculate the result.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative datastructure makes this calculation easier to reason about, performance won't be as good as other answers, but I thought worth mentioning *(mainly because it uses my favourite pandas function...)*:

```
In [11]: scores = pd.get_dummies(df['page_id']).mul(df['score'], axis=0).where(x!=0, np.nan)

In [12]: scores
Out[12]: 
                      1   2   3
date                           
2001-05-23 19:50:14   3 NaN NaN
2001-05-25 11:53:55 NaN   4 NaN
2001-05-27 17:36:37   5 NaN NaN
2001-05-28 19:36:37   1 NaN NaN
2001-05-28 19:36:38 NaN NaN   6
2001-05-28 19:36:39 NaN NaN   9

In [13]: scores.ffill()
Out[13]: 
                     1   2   3
date                          
2001-05-23 19:50:14  3 NaN NaN
2001-05-25 11:53:55  3   4 NaN
2001-05-27 17:36:37  5   4 NaN
2001-05-28 19:36:37  1   4 NaN
2001-05-28 19:36:38  1   4   6
2001-05-28 19:36:39  1   4   9

In [14]: scores.ffill().sum(axis=1)
Out[14]: 
date
2001-05-23 19:50:14     3
2001-05-25 11:53:55     7
2001-05-27 17:36:37     9
2001-05-28 19:36:37     5
2001-05-28 19:36:38    11
2001-05-28 19:36:39    14
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? But I think it's a stupid solution.

```
In [164]: df['result'] = [df[:i+1].groupby('page_id').last().sum()[0] for i in range(len(df))]

In [165]: df
Out[165]: 
                     page_id  score  result
date                                       
2001-05-23 19:50:14        1      3       3
2001-05-25 11:53:55        2      4       7
2001-05-27 17:36:37        1      5       9
2001-05-28 19:36:37        1      1       5
```

Comment: I think this is correct for the problem I described. When you say it is a stupid solution, do you mean you think there is a better pandas solution given the problem description or do you mean it should be done in another way? At first glance it seems like maybe some work is reproduced.

Comment: I guess the performance might be bad since it takes lots of `groupby` method. I just use some basic function to achieve your goal :P

Comment: Yeah, that is my thought as well. I am going to leave it open because I think there is probably a more performant answer in pandas. If nothing comes along after awhile I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: I'm also looking forward to a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interim solution I put together using the standard library. I would like to see an elegant efficient solution using pandas.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

page_scores = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
date_scores = [] # [(date, score)]

def get_and_update_score_diff(page_id, new_score):
    diff = new_score - page_scores[page_id]
    page_scores[page_id] = new_score
    return diff

# Note: there are some duplicate dates and the file is sorted by date.
# Format: 2001-05-23T19:50:14Z, 2430, 7.632989
with open('sorted_df_changes.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

    first = reader.next()
    date_string, page_id, score = first[0], first[1], float(first[2])
    page_scores[page_id] = score
    date_scores.append((date_string, score))

    for date_string, page_id, score in reader:
        score = float(score)
        score_diff = get_and_update_score_diff(page_id, score)
        if date_scores[-1][0] == date_string:
            date_scores[-1] = (date_string, date_scores[-1][1] + score_diff)
        else:
            date_scores.append((date_string, date_scores[-1][1] + score_diff))
```